# Client and Server socket connection

Tags: java, android, sockets

I'm new in java, and I have a problem. I have two android phones (Client and Server). Can anybody say me how to display on Client application the Server IP address?

Comment: Please improve your question, i couldn't get what you need.

Answer (score 0):

[Kryonet](https://github.com/EsotericSoftware/kryonet) is a very good Java library which provides a clean and simple API for efficient TCP and UDP client/server network communication using NIO. It works on Android as well.

It will make your network programming work a lot more easier, and you can get a better understanding of how to write client and server side code.

I would suggest that you try out your network programming skills using this library.

You need not even hard code any IP address of the server while in LAN. The clients can discover the server in just one line of code.

Comment: Can you tell me the line of which can discover the server, please? I just need a simple command that can find the server ip.

Comment: Well if you're using Kryonet, then this is what you'll write to discover the server: `InetAddress address = client.discoverHost(UDP_PORT, TIME_OUT);`, where UDP_PORT is the UDP port at which the server is listening, and TIME_OUT is time in milliseconds till which the search will continue. The `address` will then contain the server address with which you can then connect with. Check out Kryonet's documentation for samples and details.